Is the output of a KOA multiplier the same as a standard * multiplier when implementing GF128? where can I find test vectors for KOA multipliers?
I am trying to implement a GF128 multiplier using the KOA (Karatsuba-Ofman Algorithm) approach. I have already implemented the KOA multiplier, but I am wondering if its output is the same as the standard * multiplier in GF128. Since the KOA multiplier uses XOR in place of addition and drops the carry, I am concerned that the output may differ from that of a standard GF128 multiplier. Does anyone know if the outputs should match, or where I can find test vectors for the KOA multiplier to verify this?

KAO is just a fast multiplication algorithm, you will need reduction, too.

Yes, I am working on the reduction as well. I have implemented some Verilog code for the polynomial reduction, but it hasn't been working as expected, which led me to think the issue might be in my multiplier. Below is the polynomial reduction modulo I implemented:
function automatic logic [127:0] mod_reduction(input logic [255:0] value);     logic [255:0] temp;     temp = value;     for (int i = 255; i >= 128; i--) begin         if (temp[i]) begin             temp[i-128 -: 128] ^= reduction_poly;         end     end     return temp[127:0]; endfunction

Years ago, I did this, not hard to write test vector with SageMath, Mathmatica or Maple, etc..

Thank you for your response.
Would you happen to know if there’s a way to generate test vectors using Python, instead of SageMath, Mathematica, or Maple?
Additionally, to rephrase my original question: Is the output of the KOA multiplier (KOA(a, b)) equal to the result of standard multiplication (a * b) ?
Lastly, could you recommend any resources, papers, or links that explain polynomial reduction for multiplier results? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
